# Tikz lines don't intersect nicely

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have an issue where my lines create a non-perfect corner when they intersect. I don't really want to make a huge cycle since it's a large drawing.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thick] (0,0) -- (.25,0) -- (.25,.25) -- (.5,.25) -- (.5,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw[very thick] (1,0) -- (1,.25) -- (.75, .25) -- (.75, .5) -- (1,.5) -- (1,1);
    \draw[very thick] (1,1) -- (1.25,1) -- (1.25,1.25) -- (1.5,1.25) -- (1.5,1) -- (2,1);
    \draw[very thick] (2,1) -- (2,.75) -- (2.25,.75) -- (2.25, .5) -- (2,.5) -- (2,0);
    \draw[very thick] (2,0) -- (2.25, 0) -- (2.25, .25) -- (2.5, .25) -- (2.5,0) -- (3,0);
    \draw[very thick] (3,0) -- (3.25, 0) -- (3.25, .25) -- (3.5, .25) -- (3.5, 0) -- (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

For example, look at (1,1). I know this problem is avoided with the '--' but I don't want to do that for the entire image. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you do not say to Ti*k*Z that you want a single path, it will just end one line and start another. It has no way to know what joining you want:

[image: without line cap]

You can add [`line cap=round` to your draw](https://tikz.dev/tikz-actions#pgf./tikz/line:cap) (or global) options:

[image: with round line cap]

Or you can use `rect` also:

[image: with rect cap]

This last one seems perfect, but it works because the lines are perpendicular.

Complete MWE (please use a complete example next time!):

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        % line cap=round,
        line cap=rect,
    ]
    \draw[very thick] (0,0) -- (.25,0) -- (.25,.25) -- (.5,.25) -- (.5,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw[very thick] (1,0) -- (1,.25) -- (.75, .25) -- (.75, .5) -- (1,.5) -- (1,1);
    \draw[very thick] (1,1) -- (1.25,1) -- (1.25,1.25) -- (1.5,1.25) -- (1.5,1) -- (2,1);
    \draw[very thick] (2,1) -- (2,.75) -- (2.25,.75) -- (2.25, .5) -- (2,.5) -- (2,0);
    \draw[very thick] (2,0) -- (2.25, 0) -- (2.25, .25) -- (2.5, .25) -- (2.5,0) -- (3,0);
    \draw[very thick] (3,0) -- (3.25, 0) -- (3.25, .25) -- (3.5, .25) -- (3.5, 0) -- (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't know this, this is really helpful. I assume this extends the edge of the line into a rectangle.

Comment: Yes, you can easily see the effect on the linked page of the manual... by default, the mode is `butt`, which just cuts the line at the endpoint. Both `rect` and `round` add  "ink" extending the line half the line width, with a round or rectangular cap.

Answer (score 7):

If you convert five paths into one, won't have to worry about joins. Here you have two solutions, the first one is easy, just forget second and successive `\draw` commands. The second save you some typping using perpendicular paths.

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thick] (0,0) -- (.25,0) -- (.25,.25) -- (.5,.25) -- (.5,0) -- (1,0);
    \draw[very thick] (1,0) -- (1,.25) -- (.75, .25) -- (.75, .5) -- (1,.5) -- (1,1);
    \draw[very thick] (1,1) -- (1.25,1) -- (1.25,1.25) -- (1.5,1.25) -- (1.5,1) -- (2,1);
    \draw[very thick] (2,1) -- (2,.75) -- (2.25,.75) -- (2.25, .5) -- (2,.5) -- (2,0);
    \draw[very thick] (2,0) -- (2.25, 0) -- (2.25, .25) -- (2.5, .25) -- (2.5,0) -- (3,0);
    \draw[very thick] (3,0) -- (3.25, 0) -- (3.25, .25) -- (3.5, .25) -- (3.5, 0) -- (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thick] (0,0) -- (.25,0) -- (.25,.25) -- (.5,.25) -- (.5,0) -- (1,0) 
   -- (1,.25) -- (.75, .25) -- (.75, .5) -- (1,.5) -- (1,1) -- (1.25,1) 
   -- (1.25,1.25) -- (1.5,1.25) -- (1.5,1) -- (2,1) -- (2,.75) -- (2.25,.75) 
   -- (2.25, .5) -- (2,.5) -- (2,0) -- (2.25, 0) -- (2.25, .25) -- (2.5, .25) 
   -- (2.5,0) -- (3,0) -- (3.25, 0) -- (3.25, .25) -- (3.5, .25) -- (3.5, 0) -- (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[very thick] (0,0) -| (.25,.25) -| (.5,0) -| (1,.25) 
  -| (.75, .5) -| (1,1) -| (1.25,1.25) -| (1.5,1) -| (2,.75) -| (2.25, .5) 
  -| (2,0) -| (2.25, .25) -|  (2.5,0) -| (3.25, .25) -| (3.5, 0) -- (4,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]